# Is this partial wall load bearing?

Tags: drywall

I have a wall with a french door on top of a beam on the main floor of a two-floor building with a basement. The wall is perpendicular to the joists on top of a steel beam. In the basement, there is a column and not a wall. I tried to use a stud finder but could find 16-inch studs only. I assume that they may use a carrying beam on the top of that wall, not a load bearing. How to find out if the wall is load-bearing? If that is the case, do you think I need to add supports/ columns and augment the carrying beam?

---

**update 1**: the top of the french door is hollow. The hallway on the right of this wall does not have any header (added a photo)

**update 2**: as someone suggested, I took some photos from two recessed light holes to see if the joists are sistered. Sometimes they overlapped and sometimes they don't seem to be sistered. Added the photos.

**update 3**:

- A commenter asked if there is any wall upstairs.  there is not, except a partial 8 feet restroom wall. The whole length of the upstairs has no other wall.
- The steal beam is 177' from the front of the house with two metal posts (photo added). The partial wall on the main floor is 166' from the front of the house.
- the end of the steel beam sits on the wall in the basement on the other side of the house relative to the partial wall. So we may assume that the beam in the basement sits on the foundations (photo added).
- the house is a two-floor colonial plus a basement, made from blocks and bricks. The attic is not finished.
- no steal beem in the main floor at the center of the house. The joists are sistered over the wall. In the hallway, there is no header and lumber is using some metal attachments (photo added).

---

Videos:

[Video 1](https://share.icloud.com/photos/0a784f-eK-dze6j-kbGtQ20BQ)    |   [Video 2](https://share.icloud.com/photos/012Bh5GwdUh8a12Y07QO06L3Q)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: sistered joists adjacent to the exterior load bearing wall]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: knock on the wall above your double doors and see if they had to use an engineered beam there. If it's completely hollow between the cripple studs all the way from ceiling to header then the wall is _probably_ not load bearing. You also have electrical to the left of the door to contend with btw...

Comment: It is hollow. In the basement there is a header. There is switch on the left. Isn't easy to move the switch to the right wall?

Comment: You determine if a wall is load-bearing by looking to see what (if anything) is resting on top of it. You appear to have joist-ends resting on it. So yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

All walls above beams(not just joists) in the basement are load bearing.

The beam in the basement holds the floor and supports the wall above which supports the wall above the first wall.

Removing/changing these walls should be done with an structural engineer design, unless you to wear the roof as a hat.

Comment: Simple framing alterations do not require the services of any "structural engineer". Your statement here about walls above beams is completely false.

Answer (score 1):

If the joists run this way and sister above the wall into the next room then it is definitely load-bearing. If they don't, then it **might** be load-bearing.

[image]

Comment: This is wrong. It's absolutely possible to have a wall perpendicular to the joists which is *not* load bearing.

Comment: This can be debatable.  Would a second wall making a hall be load bearing if not above beam.  It might help with load bearing but probably not required for it.

Comment: @MikeBaranczak fixed, I forgot to specify sistering.

Comment: Ah, OK. That makes more sense.

Comment: Yes joist are running perpendicular. I am not sure how to check of the joists are sistered on top of the door, without openning the ceiling. I try to see it thru the recessed light hole a few feet onneither side of the heading.

Comment: @Roo if that wall sits on top of the beam then it is very likely load bearing. If you're interested in a minimally intrusive inspection method then get an inspection camera. This one is 16 feet for $20; https://www.amazon.com/Inspection-Waterproof-Borescope-Adjustable-Android/dp/B08X1X82DD/ref=asc_df_B08X1X82DD

Comment: Thanks for sharing the camera link. I ordered it. With the camera,  do I need to make a hole on the wall on the top of the french door to find out whether there is an engineered beam there? Or  making a hole in the ceiling to see if the 
joists are sistered there?

Comment: @Roo Ceiling is the best bet. The wall is likely to have a top plate which would prevent you from seeing the joists.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I took some photos from the recessed light holes. Comfusing... Unsure if they are sisteted or not. https://share.icloud.com/photos/0a784f-eK-dze6j-kbGtQ20BQ  https://share.icloud.com/photos/012Bh5GwdUh8a12Y07QO06L3Q

Comment: @Roo Those do seem to be sistered. Feel free to edit your question and add those videos. Maybe someone will have a different opinion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141487/discussion-between-roo-and-monkeyzeus).

Answer (score 1):

Considering the size of the house and the 70-80s construction that beam goes the length of the house and the steel post support it not the walls. Wherever the beam goes that is what's holding up your house.

The beam may be supported with wood studs at the ends and maybe some other location.

This presumes no do it yourself remodels in the past. People can mess up anything. But it's probable that you'd have problems upstairs in that case.